# C++ socket.io client over tor service

Tags: c++, node.js

I am trying to send socket requests in C++ to an onion link I am hosting with tor services and node.js. My node.js server is being hosted on port `8080`.
When I try to send socket requests to `localhost:8080`, it works perfectly fine.

However, when I try to send them to my onion link, it does not work.

The library I am using to handle sockets is https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-cpp.

The C++ code:

```
sio::client h;
connection_listener l(h);

h.set_open_listener(std::bind(&connection_listener::on_connected, &l));
h.set_close_listener(std::bind(&connection_listener::on_close, &l,std::placeholders::_1));
h.set_fail_listener(std::bind(&connection_listener::on_fail, &l));
h.connect("http://myonionlink.onion:8080/"); 
// it fails to connect to the onion link, but works perfectly fine with http://localhost:8080/
```

Why is this not working for the onion link? Do onion links work differently in this case?

Is there any method I can use to achieve this?

Comment: you probably need to implement the tor protocol?

Comment: @SebastianHoffmann how do I implement the tor protocol?

Answer (score 0):

I think problem in ".onion TLD is not in the Internet DNS root" from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.onion, under the hood library performs attempt to resolve your URL in the raw IP address and fails on it because there is not appropriate record in DNS table.

Comment: So what I am supposed to do to send sockets to my onion site?

Comment: you can set raw IP of your site if your server does not use SNI

Comment: How do I get the raw IP from my onion site? Do you mean my localhost IP? I want this to work on other networks too.

Comment: I mean set a public server IP address, you should know it, possibly check it via TOR network services, or you should find the way to connect to the site using TOR network, look at this links https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/3421/route-c-through-tor-using-socks, https://gist.github.com/anhldbk/f62fbe5e5a0e48740c6959e3e0907c81